# Filter Instagram's notification spam

Tags: android, notification, instagram

I expect notifications to be sent only for events that I can't miss out, for instance when someone comments on my picture.
Unfortunately, more than half of Instagram's notifications are just trying to get me to open the app, for barely valid reasons:

> X, Y, Z recently added to their stories.
>   Check out today's photo from the official @instagram account.

Is there an Android tool/addon that filters such Instagram notifications, and only let through the important Instagram notifications, such as when someone send me an Instagram message?

- Must work on Android and be gratis, ideally open source
- May require root